# question with integral equation

Tags: integration

I want to know how did this equation come out?
$$\int_{-1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\cos x)^{2n}}{2^x}dx=\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{2^{k\pi}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\cos x)^{2n}dx.$$
I hope you can give me some ideas, thank you！

Comment: We have:
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{k\pi}}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{2n}\;dx
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{k\pi}}\int_{-\pi/2+\pi}^{\pi/2+(k+1)\pi}(\cos x)^{2n}\;dx\approx\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{-\pi/2+\pi}^{\pi/2+(k+1)\pi}\frac{(\cos x)^{2n}}{2^x}\;dx=\int_{-\pi/2}^{-1}\frac{(\cos x)^{2n}}{2^x}\;dx+\int_{-1}^\infty\frac{(\cos x)^{2n}}{2^x}\;dx$.  See what  you can do with that.

Comment: They simply decomposed the domain in successive periods of $\cos ^2x$. But the lower bound $-1$ is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, this does not seem to be an identity but an approximation.

Since
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{+\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos ^{2 n}(x)\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n!}\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{2^{k\pi}}=\frac{2^{\pi }}{2^{\pi }-1}$$ the rhs is just
$$\text{rhs}=\frac{2^{\pi }}{2^{\pi }-1}\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n!}$$

On the other hand, the antiderivative appearing in the lhs is a real nightmare. Given by a CAS
$$\int\dfrac{\cos ^{2 n}(x)}{2^x}\,dx=-\frac{2^{-x} \left(1+e^{2 i x}\right) \cos ^{2 n}(x) \, _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2}
   i \log (2)+1;-n+\frac{1}{2} i \log (2)+1;-e^{2 i x}\right)}{\log (2)+2 i n}$$ I gave up trying to compute the values at the integration bounds and I switched to numerical integration.

The table below reproduces some results for a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{rhs} & \text{lhs} \\
 10 & 0.6242794194 & 0.6314547539 \\
 20 & 0.4441977842 & 0.4467991375 \\
 30 & 0.3634421891 & 0.3648753657 \\
 40 & 0.3150781690 & 0.3160080393 \\
 50 & 0.2819906596 & 0.2826568587 \\
 60 & 0.2575283520 & 0.2580353046 \\
 70 & 0.2384958928 & 0.2388981010 \\
 80 & 0.2231422816 & 0.2234712982 \\
 90 & 0.2104170876 & 0.2106926026 \\
 100 & 0.1996469031 & 0.1998819199
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

For $n=1$, the lhs is
$$\text{lhs}=\frac{4+2\log (2) \sin (2)+\log ^2(2) (1+\cos (2))}{\log ^3(2)+4\log (2)}\approx 1.78421$$ while the rhs is $\frac{2^{\pi -1} \pi }{2^{\pi }-1}\approx 1.77154$.